# Two python versions in my virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

So far I installed my virtualenv with `mkvirtualenv --python=python2.7 venv`.

```
(venv) ┌─╼ [~/Projects/Work_Projects]
└────╼ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p38/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
(venv) ┌─╼ [~/Projects/Work_Projects]
└────╼ python --version
Python 3.6.3
(venv) ┌─╼ [~/Projects/Work_Projects]
└────╼ python
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/infinity/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']
```

Why pip use python2.7, but my default python version is 3.6.3? How could I change that in considering I am in a virtualenv? In other words,  I want python 3.6 out my virtualenv venv and python 2.7 inside my virtualenv.